# Converting Nginx configuration to Apache

Tags: apache, nginx, apache2

I'm trying to set-up this self-hosted service but the example web configuration they give is for Nginx and I only have experience with Apache. Could someone help me write the equivalent config of below into Apache?

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
    server_name pretix.mydomain.com;
}
server {
    listen 443 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on default_server;
    server_name pretix.mydomain.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.chain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key.pem;

    add_header Referrer-Policy same-origin;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8345/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /var/pretix/data/media/;
        expires 7d;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ^~ /media/cachedfiles {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }
    location ^~ /media/invoices {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/pretix/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pretix/static.dist/;
        access_log off;
        expires 365d;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
}
```

Edit: This is what I tried as best as I could to try to translate between the two. I think I got caught up on the reverse proxy piece.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ServerName tickets.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.tickets.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/pretix/data/media/
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8345/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8345/
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

        <Directory /var/pretix/data/media/>
             AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/pretix/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pretix/static.dist/>
             AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>


Alias /media "/var/pretix/data/media/"



Alias /static "/var/pretix/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pretix/static.dist/"



<Directory /var/pretix/data/media/cachedfiles>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /var/pretix/data/media/invoices>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Directory>



        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =tickets.mydomain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.tickets.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you show us what you tried?

Comment: I updated the post with what I tried.

Comment: What's the output when you try to apply this config?

Comment: An internal service error

Comment: Could you post the Error logs?

Comment: Here's the only related apache error:

`
AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL / (scheme 'http'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
`